# Return url in PayPal without parameters

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I have connected PayPal with my eshop and I want to redirect after successfull payment back to my eshop to specific page without payment variables.
In manual is written to use parameter

```
rm=1
```

My schema looks like this:

```
 $this->form = array('cmd' => '_xclick',
        'business' => 'bis@email.tld',
        'cert_id' => 'ABCDEFGDe',
        'lc' => 'EN',
        'custom' => 'test',
        'invoice' => $orderId,
        'currency_code' => 'EUR',
        'no_shipping' => '1',
        'no_note'=>'1',
        'item_name' => 'bought item',
        'item_number' => '1',
        'rm'=>'1',
        'amount' => $price,
        'return'=> $returnURL,
        'notify_url'=>$notifyURL,

    );
```

But even though rm is set to 1 and return is set, PayPal stil redirects back to my page with all parameters with GET method (like rm=0)

Is there way to set rm=1 properly? I also tried without quotes

Answer (score 1):

According to PayPal, you need to set the `rm` parameter to `2` to get the payment details as POST parameters instead of GET parameters (`rm` set to `1`).

Also have a look at: [Paypal return URL - using GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094426/paypal-return-url-using-get-parameters)

Hope this helps - John

**Update:**
It was correct to set the `rm`parameter to `1` which makes PayPal call the return page by GET method but without GET parameters (sorry for getting this not quite right in the first place, and no pun intended).
I might have found the right solution though: In your PayPal profile, disable the transmission of payment details (on the page where you can set the default return URL).
If enabled this option seems to override the `rm` parameter whichever value the latter is set to.

John